# Automake, GNU make, check, and (ignored) pattern rules

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, check-framework

I have the following Makefile.am which is supposed to create `foo.hdb` and `foo.cdb` from `foo.h` (via the Python script):

```
TESTS = check_foo

check_PROGRAMS = check_foo

check_foo_SOURCES = check_foo.c $(top_builddir)/src/isti.h \
    foo.cdb foo.h foo.hdb
check_foo_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@ $(all_includes) -I../../clib/src/
check_foo_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libcorm.la @CHECK_LIBS@ -lsqlite3

%.hdb %.cdb: %.h
    PYTHONPATH=$(top_builddir)/cgen/src python $(top_builddir)/cgen/src/isti/cgen/run.py $<

clean-local:
    rm -f *.hdb *.cdb
```

However, although `make foo.hdb` and `make foo.cdb` work (call the Python code and generates the `foo.hdb` and `foo.cdb` files from `foo.h`), `make clean check` (or the two separately) does not (missing `foo.hdb` - no such file) - the pattern rule is not called to generate `foo.hdb` from `foo.h`.

In other words: **the pattern rule is not being called for the files listed in check_foo_SOURCES**.

How can I make this work?  The rest of the autotools infrastructure is working fine.  From looking at the Makefile I suspect the issue is with how autotools expands the check sources.

This is all on Linux with Gnu make.  Here is [the Makefile](http://pastebin.com/jLmQs33r).

[Updated slightly to reflect the help from MadScientist].

**Later update**

The following Makefile (just make, not autotools) works fine, so the issue seems to be related to autotools and check support.

```
all: check_foo

CFLAGS=-I../../clib/src
LDFLAGS=-L../../clib/src/.libs

check_foo: check_foo.c foo.h corm_foo.h corm_foo.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -lcorm -lsqlite3

corm_%.h corm_%.c: %.h
    PYTHONPATH=../../cgen/src python ../../cgen/src/isti/cgen/run.py $<

clean:
    rm -f corm_*.h corm_*.c
    rm -f *.o
```

(Note that I've switched from xxx.hdb to corm_xxx.h, etc, so that file extensions remain OK).

**More Details**

Since it seems to be related to the CHECK macros, this is configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([corm], [0.1], [a.cooke@isti.com])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([CHECK], [check >= 0.9.4]) 
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall foreign -Werror])
AC_PROG_CC_C99
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile clib/Makefile clib/src/Makefile clib/tests/Makefile clib/docs/Makefile cgen/Makefile cgen/docs/Makefile example/Makefile example/src/Makefile])
AC_CHECK_PROGS([DOXYGEN], [doxygen], AC_MSG_WARN([Doxygen not found - continuing without Doxygen support]))
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_DOXYGEN], [test -n "$DOXYGEN"])
AM_COND_IF([HAVE_DOXYGEN], [AC_CONFIG_FILES([clib/docs/Doxyfile cgen/docs/Doxyfile])])
```

**SOLUTION**

OK, so summarizing the various things below, there were two important issues (once I had fixed file extensions - see the "plain" makefile and fceller's answer), either one of which was sufficient to make things work:

1. (The handling of) Header files is complicated.  Because of auto-dependencies, programatically generated header files break things.  The solution is to use [BUILT_SOURCES](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Sources.html)
2. But (the handling of) .c files is not complicated.  So putting the corm_foo.c in front of check_foo.c would trigger the generation of that file.  Since that also generates corm_foo.h, everything works (because check_foo.c now can include corm_foo.h).

Also, fceller has some good general points about tidy makefiles and explains why the "plain" makefile works.

Comment: What is your `Makefile`? Could you please add it on a pastebin if it is too large for the question

Comment: hi - i've added it (pastebin link) to the question, thanks.

Comment: What does `find . -name foo.hdb` output?

Comment: `make foo.hdb` creates foo.hdb, but it is deleted by the `clean` in `make clean check` (see the clean-local target).  so, if i do the `find` after `make clean` it shows nothing.  maybe i am misunderstanding your question, but i think you are on the wrong track (and the above Makefile.am is in a directory with no children).

Comment: and also, of course, it shows nothing after `make clean check`.  that is the problem - the file is not being created.

Comment: Have you tried adding `BUILT_SOURCES = foo.hdb`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell - THANK-YOU.  YES (or rather, no, i had not)! THIS FIXES IT.  Please post as a "real" answer and I'll assign the bounty (not that you need it ;o).

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Sources.html for the curious.

Comment: also, since both the h and c files are generated together, swapping the order of check_foo.c and corm_foo.c will work, since the.c file is auto-generated (unlike headers) and that (because of the new ordering) occurs before the header file is needed by check_foo.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell automake that `foo.hdb` is a source file that is to be constructed.  Add the following to Makefile.am:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = foo.hdb
```

Comment: @fceller has been very helpful, but it was this comment that made me understand what was happening.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
%.cdb: %.hdb
```

does not do anything.  Check the GNU make manual and you'll see that a pattern rule without a command line is used to DELETE a previously defined rule with that same pattern.  Since there's no previous rule, this is essentially a no-op.

If you have a command that creates TWO output files with ONE invocation of a rule, then you need to put both patterns in the same rule, like this:

```
%.cdb %.hdb: %.h
        PYTHONPATH=$(top_builddir)/cgen/src python $(top_builddir)/cgen/src/isti/cgen/run.py $<
```

This will tell GNU make that both targets are generated from one invocation of the rule.  BE AWARE!  This syntax only has this behavior for pattern rules.  Explicit rules with multiple targets do something entirely different (confusingly enough).

As for the `make clean` behavior, I'm not sure.  The makefile generated by automake is too complex for me to just read it; it would require some debugging (run it and trace what happens).  However, I suspect that the rules there are not designed properly to allow a `clean` target and a build target to both be run in the same invocation of make.  Run the two commands separately and see if that works better:

```
make clean
make check
```

Comment: thanks for the fix for hdb/cdb (i had followed the instructions for multiple outputs from explicit rules).  however, this doesn't affect the main issue (which isn't related to clean - doing them separately has the same problem).  so apologies for posting (in retrospect) a question with two problems - i don't want to make this as correct as it doesn't get things working (but have an upvote!).  also, i will update the question to reflect this answer.  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you do not need to include the "*.h" in *_SOURCES. The automake will generated code to generate the dependencies. From the manual: Header files listed in a _SOURCES definition will be included in the distribution but otherwise ignored

The change you made in the plain Makefile ("Note that I've switched from xxx.hdb to corm_xxx.h, etc, so that file extensions remain OK") is essential. The automake FILTERS the *_SOURCES list using the filename extension in order to see what to call (CC, CXX, F77).

The following Makefile.am will work:

```
TEST = check_foo

check_PROGRAMS = check_foo

check_foo_SOURCES = check_foo.c foo.db.c
check_foo_CFLAGS = 
check_foo_LDADD = 

%.db.c %.db.h: %.h
    echo "int i = 1;" > foo.db.c
    echo "int j;" > foo.db.h

clean-local:
    rm -f *.db.h *.db.c
```

Comment: that didn't fix things - it needs either the order of the .c files to be swapped, or BUILT_SOURCES to be used.  which makes sense, but i do not understand why the "ordinary" makefile i gave worked.  anyway, thanks for the general suggestions on tidying.

Comment: If you do not include "foo.db.h" the above works. If you include "foo.db.h" in "check_foo.c" you either need to BUILT_SOURCE

Comment: If you do not include "foo.db.h" the above works. If you include "foo.db.h" in "check_foo.c" you either need to use BUILT_SOURCE because the VERY first time you do a make, the dependencies have not been generated, so make does not know that "check_foo.c" needs "foo.db.h" (you will notice that it works if you do "make -k" once and let the .deps files be generated). Reversing the order of the files does not help, because a "make -j 2" will still break.

Comment: The makefile you gave works differently: The automake generated Makefile compiles every file by itself, allowing for parallel make. Your makefile compiles everything in one command - therefore make has to generated all files before starting the compile.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to add an indirect answer/discussion to the existing direct ones.

I recently moved away from `make` for the same kind of reasons you experienced: it is extremely powerful but sometimes a bit difficult to debug when things do not go as expected.

I recently discovered [pydoit](https://pydoit.org/) which is very promising as a debuggable replacement build tool for make. Since the notion of "pattern rules" was not present in it, I proposed an independent package to do the job: [fprules](https://smarie.github.io/python-fprules/).

This is how you would perform the same task that you mention in your post, with `doit` and `fprules`:

```
from fprules import file_pattern

# all: check_foo
DOIT_CONFIG = {'default_tasks': ['check_foo']}

CFLAGS = '-I../../clib/src'
LDFLAGS = '-L../../clib/src/.libs'

# check_foo: check_foo.c foo.h corm_foo.h corm_foo.c
#     gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -lcorm -lsqlite3
def task_check_foo():
    """
    Compiles the `check_foo` executable
    """
    src_files = ('check_foo.c', 'foo.h', 'corm_foo.h', 'corm_foo.c')
    dst_file = 'check_foo'
    return {

        'file_dep': src_files,
        'actions': ["gcc %s %s %s -o %s -lcorm -lsqlite3" % (CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, ' '.join(src_files), dst_file)],
        'verbosity': 2,
        'targets': [dst_file],
        'clean': True
    }

# corm_%.h corm_%.c: %.h
#     PYTHONPATH=../../cgen/src python ../../cgen/src/isti/cgen/run.py $<
def task_gen_corm():
    """
    Generates files `corm_%.h` and `corm_%.c`
    for each header file `%.h`.
    """
    for data in file_pattern('./*.h', dict(h_file='./corm_%.h', c_file='./corm_%.c')):
        yield {
            'name': data.name,
            'file_dep': [data.src_path],
            'actions': ["PYTHONPATH=../../cgen/src python ../../cgen/src/isti/cgen/run.py %s" % data.src_path],
            'verbosity': 2,
            'targets': [data.h_file, data.c_file],
            'clean': True
        }

# clean:
#     rm -f corm_*.h corm_*.c
#     rm -f *.o
# No need to create tasks for this: 
# with 'clean': True, `doit clean` will clean all target files
```

Then simply run `doit` in the folder.

Do not hesitate to provide feedback on the projects pages if needed: for example multiline commands are not supported, you can vote for them if you too feel that they are missing: https://github.com/pydoit/doit/issues/314